# How to generate Latex file for each reST(reStructuredText) file?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to write some documentation. I can generate PDF file by using "make latexpdf", but all the rst files will be built into a single PDF file.

How to generate PDF/Latex output for each rst file? I don't want to create projects for each rst file.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use Sphinx for that? Or could you just call `rst2latex` for each document?

Comment: What does your Makefile look like?